# Area lights not rendering on single frame in animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, light

I have a blender animation that I have been trying to render, but I discovered that for no apparent reason, a single frame consistently renders without any of the area lights in the scene.  I have re-rendered it several times, but it is always significantly darker than the frames immediately before and after it.  Is there any explanation for why this is happening, and how to fix it?

[Download the blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1635/)

Frame 86: (How the animation is supposed to look)
[image]

Frame 87: (How this one frame looks)
[image]

Comment: You might want to pack all the external data into the .blend file and then upload it again because we cannot see textures or your baked fluid. To do so you have to go File => External Data => Pack All Into .blend

Comment: I packed the texture in, but the baked fluid is 250Mb, so I'm not sure what to do about that

Comment: The particle bake is still running for me... but in meantime, I have notice that your fluid material has two chained shaders (diffuse as input for glass)... AFAIK this is not a normal setting

Comment: There is only one missing texture in the file and I don't think it will change something significantly even if packed. I wasn't able to repeat that behaviour with UV grid texture assigned to the floor, with frames 77, 86, 87 and 89 rendered (I used lower quality for fluid baking though). The only thing to suggest as of now - do not plug output from Diffuse BSDF to Color input of Glass BSDF; plug a simple color (fluid material)

Comment: Rendered frame 87, after a fuid bake from the settings of your file : https://i.gyazo.com/9951a28f0f2420ed6f91a46b06aff33e.png... so there is something else. On which system are you working (OS, Blender version, GPU..) ?

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.77a on Windows 10 x64 with a GTX 750ti, but it does the same thing when I render it on any one of my other computers

Comment: I am on Blender 2.77a, Windows 10 x64, GTX 980M. So very close to yours. As a placeholder I can render this frame for you if we don't find the solution here (but yes this is not an explanation)